# Azure durable function call activtity function in foreach loop. Is it OK?

Tags: azure, azure-durable-functions

**Is it ok to call activity function in a loop, like this: ?**

```
foreach(var item in items)
{
    await context.CallActivityWithRetryAsync(....,item,...);
}
```

expanding on the problem I need to execute 2 activities sequentially inside the loop

```
var tasks = new List<Task<TypeA>>();

foreach(var item in items)
{
    var task = context.CallActivityWithRetryAsync(Activity2Name,item,...);

    tasks.Add(task);

    task.ContinueWith(t => {
        var innerTask =  context.CallActivityWithRetryAsync(Activity3Name,t.Result,...);
        return innerTask;
    },TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously );
}
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

I should maybe add inner tasks to task collection somehow, so await will wait on all tasks. And then get rid of the TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously ?

Above thing works. But I'm not sure if its the right way to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good question. I'm not a 100% sure if there's a problem but here's my guess: Your durable context will be executed multiple times, so you'd better await for all the activities outside the loop.

```
var tasks = new Task<long>[files.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
{
        tasks[i] = context.CallActivityWithRetryAsync("FunctionName", files[i]);
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

At least this is the way I've been using successfully in my projects

Comment: Sure thing I'm investigating something in that direction. Thx. For suggesting

Comment: Do you have some call like ContinueAsNew or similar?

Comment: Following above patterns doesn't seem to help. Looks like orchestration just ends

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I get list of ids in  activity1. Now I want to loop over ids and fetch resource by id in activity2 and then put resource to a queue in activity3. So I Try to use task2.ContinuesWith(=> activity3). Don't know if thats comprehensible

Comment: but do you need to wait the completion of each call to activity2 ?

Comment: Activity 2 to be called before activity 3 , so 2 and 3 should be linked together. but each iteration in the loop are independent. I Had to use ContinuesWith (..., ExecuteSynchonously). MAybe because WhenAll(tasks) only waits for  the activity 2 . tasks